# static inner class treated as static member or normal class?

Tags: java

As we know, static members has shared memory, they have no concern with object:

```
class TestStatic {
    public static int a = 10;
}

class Main{
    public static void main(//){
        TestStatic obj1 = new TestObj//;
        obj1.a=15;
        TestStatic obj2 = new TestObj//;
        // obj2.a equals 15 too
    }
}
```

Suppose we have following scenario:

```
class TestStatic {

    public static class InnerClass {
    }

    public static void main(//) {
         TestStatic.InnerClass classobj1 = new TestStatic.InnerClass();
         TestStatic.InnerClass classobj2 = new TestStatic.InnerClass();
    }

}
```

How Java treats `classobj1` and `classobj2`? Allocates two different memory locations or a shared one? If different memory locations, what is the reason?

Comment: Java trivia, therefore -1.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> how java treats classobj1 and classobj2? allocate two different memory location or shared one?

Two separate ones. Exactly as though you had:

```
Map m1 = new HashMap();
Map m2 = new HashMap();
```

> if different memory location, what is the reason?

Because the `static` here relates to the *class*, not to instances of the class. If you have a nested class that isn't `static`, it's related to *instances* of the containing class.

The Oracle [Nested Class Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/nested.html) may be useful.